# How To Integrate NodeJS and Phonegap For RealTime Data

Tags: node.js, cordova, chat

I would like to create a realtime chat phonegap app using nodejs for realtime. But I am not even sure whether it is possible or not.I am a newbie to nodejs. I really appreciate any answers.

Comment: i just wanted to create a simple chat mobile app.i saw examples and tutorials how to do it on nodejs but was not sure it can be deployed as a phonegap mobile app.but now i got it.

Comment: Hello @Nay can you share how you got phonegap working with nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of solution to create a real time chat in node js.
I will advice following one of those tutorial that were really useful to me.
http://tutorialzine.com/2014/03/nodejs-private-webchat/ 
http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ 

 
Make it work locally on your web browser and it will need only little UI modification to make it work on devices. 
 Hope this help.

Comment: thanks.i got it now.